# C++ for loop: evaluation of condition

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have got a (stupid?) C / C++ question about a loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < std::distance(begin, end); ++i) {
  a.push_back(i);
}
```

`begin` and `end` are two iterator. My question is, is `std::distance(begin, end)` calculated for each element in the loop? Or is it better to use this version:

```
size_t dist = std::distance(begin, end);
for (size_t i = 0; i < dist; ++i) {
  a.push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I was of the mind that the first one can be significantly slower. I don't think compilers would be able to figure out that `std::distance(begin, end)` is constant, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @quasiverse: you're wrong, I'm afraid :-S Thanks to iterator categories and trait checks, random-access iterators allow for a constant-time implementation of `distance`. Check out your compiler's implementation!

Comment: A simplified and related version of the question is if in `for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)` the call to `v.end()` is performed in each round or not. The standard requires that the program behave *as if* it is called each time, so the compiler can only optimize it out if it can prove that the result is always the same (and that there are no side effects).

Comment: @Kerrel: *if* it's a random-access iterator. But quasiverse said that it *can* be significantly slower. For example, when begin/end are not random-access, then it becomes rather important whether `distance` is hoisted. If the compiler can't do it then the programmer should.

Comment: @SteveJessop: That's true, sorry for that -- I mainly wanted to point out that `distance` isn't necessarily inefficient, and that it's as good as it can be. As with everything about this question, we'd need to see more code to be more specific.

Comment: Note that you can scope the extra variable inside the loop if you want: `for (size_t i = 0, dist = std::distance(begin, end); i < dist; ++i)`.

Comment: Please indicate the type of `begin`, `end`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second version is better. In the first one the condition is evaluated each time (no automatic asumption about the result being invariant).

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The second version is better.

As for the first version, if the container type `a` is `std::vector`, *and* `begin` and `end` are iterators of `a`, then the `push_back` operation might cause resizing the vector, which in turn will invalidate `begin` and `end` iterators, and using them to calculate the distance in the next iteration will invoke *undefined behaviour*. In this case, the second is not only better, it is *well-defined* as well.

Comment: Wait, who said anything about `begin` and `end` being iterators to `a`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Good point. I assumed so :P. Let me add this assumption to my answer.

Comment: I was pretty sure that the iterators can actually *not* point to the container in question, since otherwise that loop would never terminate (unless the OP is actually confused about that point, but I didn't get tham impression).

Comment: @KerrekSB: Maybe, or maybe not. I simply thought to add this for a record.

Comment: @Kerrek: but from the optimization POV it's irrelevant whether the *questioner* is confused on the issue, what matters is whether the *compiler* knows that the loop isn't infinite! Without seeing the surrounding code of course we can't tell what the compiler knows.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, this depends on the compiler optimizations. IF they are turned off, the `std::distance` will be executed on each loop, and this is for sure. The reason - the iterators may be changed inside the loop's body.

So, if you're not changing the iterators, prefer the second version, even thought it's very small optimization.
In most cases, it's a matter of personal choice ( if this is not a bottle neck, which is very unlikely).

---

***EDIT*** My answer assumes, that `begin` and `end` in your code are **NOT** the `begin` and `end` of the vector (or whatever it is) `a`. If they are, then the answer to your question depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: The returned value could change even if the inputs are not changing. Yes, std::distance() won't work like this, but the compiler / optimizer cannot know (generically).

Comment: Are there really any compilers that would be intelligent enough to realise that the `std::distance` value was invariant?

Comment: @Raedwald: sure, depending what `begin` and `end` are. For example with `std::vector<int> v(5); std::vector<int>::const_iterator begin = v.begin(), end = v.end();`, GCC 4.5.3 with -O2, I get `add $0x1,%ebx // cmp $0x5,%ebx` in the loop. Not only does it realize that the `std::distance` result is invariant, it computes it at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

Without optimization, it is really computed every time. In practice with optimization, it shouldn't make a difference. If it is crucial that it isn't calculated every time (e.g. because this is your most inner thing to do), you can always play it safe and go with the second one.

Comment: Even with optimization it should make a difference... the compiler does not know that `std::distance(begin, end)` will return a constant value and so it must check each iteration.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about that. I assume std::distance to tget inlined anyway and furthjer optimizations might be able to detect that the result can't possibly change.

Comment: "_might be able_" Might be able, but it depends on many factors.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the compiler can perform the optimization depends (at least) on the types involved. For example, if `begin` and `end` are list iterators, and `a` is a list, and `end` is an iterator at the end of `a`, then this is an infinite loop (until out-of-memory occurs). The compiler cannot make the "optimization" if it changes the meaning of the program. Presumably it doesn't change the meaning of the program or you wouldn't ask the question, but still the compiler must somehow rule out that possibility, for example by tracking the value of `end` from wherever it was set. In some cases it might be obvious to you, but beyond the power of the compiler to prove.

Conversely, if `begin` and `end` are vector iterators, then in practice they're either a pointer or a thin wrapper around one. Then the compiler might well be able to see that their values never change in the loop, and hence their distance never changes, and make the optimization. Even if it doesn't make the optimization, though, `distance` is cheap for vector iterators. So the optimization may not be all that significant anyway in that case.

Con-conversely, a checking implementation of a vector iterator might in theory include code to see whether the vector has been reallocated since the iterator was taken (and hence the iterator is no longer valid). This fact *can* change in the loop, so if `std::distance` indirectly invokes that check, then on that implementation it can't be hoisted. Not that you'd usually combine a checking iterator with optimization, but it's possible.

As ever, optimization is implementation-dependent. If you really care you need to look at the code emitted by the compiler(s) you care about.

And for what it's worth, for your second snippet some people prefer this style:

```
for (size_t i = 0, dist = std::distance(begin, end); i < dist; ++i) {
  a.push_back(i);
}
```

It relies on the types in the comparison being the same, but it avoids putting `dist` into the surrounding scope, where it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Both will have the same performance as any decent compiler will convert the code into second version. IF compiler optimization is turned off, use the second version.

Comment: "_any decent compiler will convert the code into second version_" Which compilers are "decent"?

Comment: subjective answer...but any compiler which performs the basics right and is good with general optimizations is a decent compiler. Now definition of those basic functions and general optimizations may vary from person to person making the whole concept of decent compiler little subjective ;)

Comment: `distance` of `list<>::iterator` is not as easy to optimise as `distance` of `vector<>::iterator`.